# transparent (test) grid showing up when rendering?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

When I'm rendering, I've noticed that there is the transparent grid, even with the user's perspective filled with non-empty texture.
How can I get rid of that?
[image: screenshot]

Comment: You have something strange going on with your alpha channel. Please include a snapshot of the the compositor in the question.

Comment: where can i find the compositor? (sorry i'm a beginner)

Comment: Do you have any textures in your scene, or just solid colors?

Comment: Please upload your blend file so we can see all the details of how your scene is set up, since this problem could be caused by many things. If you need a place to upload to, you can use [PasteAll.org](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/) -- it's very easy to use: http://www.pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: http://www.pasteall.org/blend/28986

I do have one image texture of the macbook, and some glasses which are disabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rendered scene you posted seems to be from an earlier version of your blend file than the one you posted. When I render using the blend file you posted, I don't have any transparency problems:

[image]

Try rendering again and see if you still have the problem.

One thing about your file I noticed is that on frame 1, the camera itself is positioned partially inside the wall:

[image]

The part circled in green is where the camera sees from, *not* from the front, shown here in red:

[image]

That results in your scene at frame 1 of your animation being partially obscured by the wall, like this:

[image]

To fix this, simply move the camera at frame 1 fully into the room, then set a keyframe for it:

[image]

Comment: I'm on 2.69a. It looked fine with less path tracing sample, but once i get more path tracing samples, the transparent grid appears, as shown in the screenshot I had in the question.

Comment: Are you using the render with render active scene, or just the previewing one (I hope you understand what I'm trying to say)?

Comment: I'm using Render Active Scene -- is that what you were using?

Comment: @Rouvis I don't think there is a 2.69a. Are you using a development version? In the viewport render I've rendered to 150 samples without any transparency showing up in 2.70a.. Does it work if you disable *Transparent* in *Render settings > Film*?

Comment: @Rouvis I tried rendering it at 500 samples using 2.69 and there wasn't any problem with transparency. Are you still finding you having the same problem?

Comment: I woke up and the problem dramatically disappeared. Thanks for the help from everyone :)